# Async function depends on a external module in Protractor test

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, webdriver-io

I want to

1. **save the image file** which is in remote web server, and
2. **upload it** to another server

in Protractor Test.

```
// depend on a external module
var fs = require('fs');

// save remote file(url) to local(dest)
var download = function (url, dest) {

    // let this function be async
    browser.executeAsyncScript(function (url, dest, done) {

        var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
        var request = http.get(url, function (response) {
            response.pipe(file);
            file.on('finish', function () {
                file.close(done);
            });
        });
    }, url, dest);
};

describe('', function () {
    it('', function () {
        browser.get('http://...');

        download('http://.../foo.jpg', 'foo.jpg'); /*** DOESN'T WORK! ***/

        var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'foo.jpg');
        $('input[type=file]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
        $('#uploadButton').click();
        ...
```

but this doesn't work:

```
   Stacktrace:
     UnknownError: javascript error: fs is not defined
```

When I put `var fs = require('fs');` in `download` function, the error message is below:

```
   Stacktrace:
     UnknownError: javascript error: require is not defined
```

Comment: Going out on a limb here but do Protractor tests run in the browser? Or in Node? Because if they ran in the browser then that would explain why `require` isn't working.

Comment: @Jackson Quote from [protractor github page](https://github.com/angular/protractor#protractor-):
'Protractor is an end-to-end test framework for AngularJS applications. Protractor is a Node.js program built on top of WebDriverJS.'

Comment: @weed maybe you need to require your file from another directory e.g.: `var fs = require('../fs');` - depending on your project setup.

Comment: never mind, you are right, it should work: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#taking-screenshots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `executeAsyncScript` the function that you pass is serialized an executed inside the browser. The function will not run in the context of your protractor test, but on the browser.

You need to create a promise that resolves when you are done downloading the file.

```
// depend on a external module
var fs = require('fs');

describe('', function () {

  // save remote file(url) to local(dest)
  var download = function (url, dest) {
      // Create a promise that will be resolved after download.
      var d = protractor.promise.defer();

      var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
      var request = http.get(url, function (response) {
          response.pipe(file);
          file.on('finish', function () {
              file.close();
              // The file has been read, resolve the promise
              d. fulfill();
          });
      });

      // Return the promise
      d.promise;
  };

  it('', function () {
      browser.get('http://...');

      // Get the file and wait for the promise to resolve to move on
      download('http://.../foo.jpg', 'foo.jpg').then(function() {
          // Make sure you specify a path where you can write and read the file.
          var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'foo.jpg');
          $('input[type=file]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
          $('#uploadButton').click();
          ...
      });
```

Let me know if it works

Here is the documentation: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Deferred_Objects

Comment: Absolutely brilliant.  I stumbled down many ratholes before finding this.  Thanks very much!